# Decimal type in Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, decimal

What is the correct type to use in Qt development (or C++ in general) for decimal arithmetic, i.e. the equivalent of `System.Decimal` struct in .Net?

- Does Qt provide a built-in struct? (I can't find it in the docs, but maybe don't know where to look.)
- Is there a "standard" C++ library to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the correct type to use in Qt
>   development (or C++ in general) for
>   decimal arithmetic, i.e. the
>   equivalent of System.Decimal struct in
>   .Net?

Neither C++ standard library nor Qt has any data type equivalent to `System.Decimal` in .NET.

> Does Qt provide a built-in struct? (I
>   can't find it in the docs, but maybe
>   don't know where to look.)

No.

> Is there a "standard" C++ library to
>   use?

No.

But you might want to have a look at the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/).

[EDIT:] A better choice than the above library might be [qdecimal](http://code.google.com/p/qdecimal/). It wraps an IEEE-compliant decimal float, which is very similar (but not exactly the same as) the .NET decimal, as well utilizing Qt idioms and practices.

Answer (score 2):

There is no decimal type in C++, and to my knowledge, there is none provided by Qt either. Depending on your range of values, a decent solution may be to just use an `unsigned int` and divide/multiply by a power of ten when displaying it.

For example, if we are talking about dollars, you could do this:

`unsigned int d = 100; // 1 dollar, basically d holds cents here...`

or if you want 3 decimal places and wanted to store `123.456`

`unsigned int x = 123456;` and just do some simply math when displaying:

`printf("%u.%u\n", x / 1000, x % 1000);`

Comment: You need to zero-pad the decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about Qt, [but there is a decimal floating point library from Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/).

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turns up that gcc may support decimals directlyand that far more general information is available at for instance http://speleotrove.com/decimal/

Answer (score 1):

There is also an implementation in C, available from IBM : http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/decNumber