# correct input value with toFloat() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, format, precision, qstring

I want to change text into float number for calculation in Qt

```
float test = ui.tableWidget->item(0, 1)->text().replace(",", ".", Qt::CaseSensitive).toFloat();
```

when I type 2.86, actually I see `test = 2.85999990` in debug. How can I receive correctly what i typed ?

I can use this for showing

```
qDebug() << QString::number( test, 'f', 2 );
```

But I want a value for calculation, not for showing.

Comment: Unfortunately floating point numbers won't give you much more precise results. This is the way they are - you usually get the closest number that can be expressed in *some size* floating point number. I'd recommend reading some wikipedia on the reasons why (take a look at the equations there). Note: `double` could give you slightly better results.

Comment: @hauron: thank you. Yes, I have checked with `double`, but the result is just slightly better as you said. Do we have any way to receive exactly what we want ?

Answer (score 1):

As @hauron already said this is format specific but normal behaviour. You might want to take a read on [this](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf).

Additionally you might also take a look at another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547746/6385043). Using some additional library may work for you, if applicable.

Comment: thank you, i decided to use `double`, the result after that will be rounded, looks also ok.